Cannot launch maps in CarPlay from my app
In the application I made with Flutter, I integrated CarPlay with the flutter_carplay package. When an item is clicked on the POI screen in Carplay, it needs to open the map in Carplay and navigate to the location of that item.
To reproduce create a flutter app and add the flutter_carplay plugin replace the FCPPointOfInterest.swift code in that and use a POI template and try to navigate from carplay.
I have attached the code of FCPPointOfInterest. I have changed the plugin code
  //
//  FCPPointOfInterest.swift
//  Runner
//
//  Created by Olaf Schneider on 15.02.22.
//

import CarPlay

@available(iOS 14.0, *)
class FCPPointOfInterest {
    private(set) var _super: CPPointOfInterest?
    private(set) var elementId: String
    private var latitude: Double
    private var longitude: Double
    private var title: String
    private var subtitle: String?
    private var summary: String?
    private var detailTitle: String?
    private var detailSubtitle: String?
    private var detailSummary: String?
    private var image: String?

    private var primaryButton: CPTextButton?
    private var objcPrimaryButton: FCPTextButton?

    private var secondaryButton: CPTextButton?
    private var objcSecondaryButton: FCPTextButton?

    static let maxPinImageSize: CGFloat = 40

    init(obj: [String: Any]) {
        self.elementId = obj["_elementId"] as! String

        let lat = obj["latitude"] as! NSNumber
        self.latitude = lat.doubleValue

        let lng = obj["longitude"] as! NSNumber
        self.longitude = lng.doubleValue
        self.title = obj["title"] as! String
        self.subtitle = obj["subtitle"] as? String
        self.summary = obj["summary"] as? String
        self.detailTitle = obj["detailTitle"] as? String
        self.detailSubtitle = obj["detailSubtitle"] as? String
        self.detailSummary = obj["detailSummary"] as? String
        self.image = obj["image"] as? String

        let primaryButtonData = obj["primaryButton"] as? [String: Any]
        if primaryButtonData != nil {
            self.objcPrimaryButton = FCPTextButton(obj: primaryButtonData!)

            // Create a new CPTextButton with all required parameters
            let button = CPTextButton(
                title: self.objcPrimaryButton?.get.title ?? "",
                textStyle: .normal,  // You can change to .confirm if needed
                handler: { [weak self] _ in
                    self?.launchGoogleMapsWithCarPlay()
                }
            )

            self.primaryButton = button
        }
        let secondaryButtonData = obj["secondaryButton"] as? [String: Any]
        if secondaryButtonData != nil {
            self.objcSecondaryButton = FCPTextButton(obj: secondaryButtonData!)
            self.secondaryButton = self.objcSecondaryButton?.get
        }
    }
    func launchGoogleMapsWithCarPlaytry() {
        // Create the Google Maps URL with the destination coordinates
        let urlString = "comgooglemaps://?daddr=\(latitude),\(longitude)&directionsmode=driving"

        // Check if Google Maps is installed
        if let url = URL(string: urlString), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
            // Open Google Maps
            UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        } else {
            // Fallback to Apple Maps if Google Maps isn't installed
            let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
            let placemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinate)
            let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: placemark)

            let launchOptions: [String: Any] = [
                MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey: MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving,
                MKLaunchOptionsShowsTrafficKey: true,
                MKLaunchOptionsMapTypeKey: MKMapType.standard.rawValue,
            ]

            mapItem.openInMaps(launchOptions: launchOptions)
        }
    }

  

    

    func launchGoogleMapsWithCarPlay() {
        // Check if app is running in CarPlay mode
        guard let carPlayScene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first(where: { $0 is CPTemplateApplicationScene }) as? CPTemplateApplicationScene,
              let interfaceController = carPlayScene.delegate as? CPTemplateApplicationSceneDelegate else {
            // If CarPlay is not connected, fall back to mobile navigation
//            launchMobileNavigation()
            return
        }
        
        // Create the Google Maps URL specifically for CarPlay
        let urlString = "comgooglemaps://?daddr=\(latitude),\(longitude)&directionsmode=driving"
        
        if let url = URL(string: urlString), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
            // Open Google Maps
            UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        } else {
            // Fallback to Apple Maps if Google Maps isn't installed
            let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
            let placemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinate)
            let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: placemark)
            
            let launchOptions: [String: Any] = [
                MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey: MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving,
                MKLaunchOptionsShowsTrafficKey: true,
                MKLaunchOptionsMapTypeKey: MKMapType.standard.rawValue
            ]
            
            mapItem.openInMaps(launchOptions: launchOptions)
        }
    }


    // Fallback function for mobile navigation
    private func launchMobileNavigation() {
        let urlString = "comgooglemaps://?daddr=\(latitude),\(longitude)&directionsmode=driving"
        
        if let url = URL(string: urlString), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        } else {
            let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
            let placemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinate)
            let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: placemark)
            
            let launchOptions: [String: Any] = [
                MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey: MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving,
                MKLaunchOptionsShowsTrafficKey: true,
                MKLaunchOptionsMapTypeKey: MKMapType.standard.rawValue
            ]
            
            mapItem.openInMaps(launchOptions: launchOptions)
        }
    }

    

    private func launchMapsApp() {
        if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string: "comgooglemaps://")!) {
            if let url = URL(
                string: "comgooglemaps://?daddr=\(latitude),\(longitude)&directionsmode=driving")
            {
                UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
            }
        } else {
            if let url = URL(
                string:
                    "https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&destination=\(latitude),\(longitude)&travelmode=driving"
            ) {
                UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
            }
        }
    }

    var get: CPPointOfInterest {

        let location = MKMapItem(
            placemark: MKPlacemark(
                coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)))
        var pinImage: UIImage? = nil

        if let image = self.image {
            let key = SwiftFlutterCarplayPlugin.registrar?.lookupKey(forAsset: image)

            pinImage = UIImage(named: key!)
            if let pImage = pinImage {
                if pImage.size.height > FCPPointOfInterest.maxPinImageSize
                    || pImage.size.width > FCPPointOfInterest.maxPinImageSize
                {
                    pinImage = pImage.resizeImageTo(
                        size: CGSize(
                            width: FCPPointOfInterest.maxPinImageSize,
                            height: FCPPointOfInterest.maxPinImageSize))
                }
            }
        }
        let poi = CPPointOfInterest(
            location: location, title: title, subtitle: subtitle, summary: summary,
            detailTitle: detailTitle, detailSubtitle: detailSubtitle,
            detailSummary: detailSummary, pinImage: pinImage)

        if let primaryButton = self.primaryButton {
            poi.primaryButton = primaryButton

        }
        if let secondaryButton = self.secondaryButton {
            poi.secondaryButton = secondaryButton
        }

        self._super = poi
        return poi
    }
}


You need to provide much more information. What CarPlay template are you using? How are you trying to launch the directions in maps?

I am using EV charging carplay template.

@Paulw11 I have added the code. I am newbie in swift.

You can't use UIApplication to open a url from a CarPlay scene.   You need to use the CPTemplateApplicationScene that was passed to your CarPlay scene delegate. Also, you can't open a MKMapItem; you need to use a maps: url. Apple has some sample code.

Also, just because Google maps is installed, it doesn't mean that that is the users preferred map. I have google maps installed but I prefer Apple Maps. You could consider having a preference in your iOS app. That way you could also offer other options, such as Waze, which many people may use in the car

Thanks @Paulw11. It works. Thanks a lot. Considered opening both Gmaps and Apple Maps great idea.
